# What are the analogues of Littlewood-Richardson coefficients for monomial symmetric polynomials?

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

The product of monomial symmetric polynomials can be expressed as
$m_{\lambda} m_{\mu} = \Sigma c_{\lambda\mu}^{\nu}m_{\nu}$
for some constants $c_{\lambda\mu}^{\nu}$.

In the case of Schur polynomials, these constants are called the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients. What are they called for monomial symmetric polynomials, and how do I calculate them?

Comment: I once had a similar [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/83214/19341) with a very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [reference](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001CoPhC.141..282C), where the authors deal with the products you asked for.

---

*EDIT* The reference is

*A MAPLE program for calculations with Schur functions*
by M.J. Carvalho, S. D’Agostino
Computer Physics Communications 141 (2001) 282–295

---

From the paper (p.5 chap. 3.1 *Multiplication and division of $m$-functions*):

> Let’s define the result of the addition
>   and subtraction of two partitions $(\mu_1,\mu_2, . . .)$
>   and $(\nu_1, \nu_2, . . .)$ as being the partition whose parts are
>   $(\mu_1 ± \nu_1,\mu_2 ± \nu_2, . . .)$. For these operations to be
>   meaningful, it is necessary that both partitions have
>   an equal number of parts; if they do not, then one
>   increases the number of parts of the shortest one by
>   adding enough zeros at the end. ... The multiplication (and division) of two m-functions
>   are then defined as
>   $$
> m_{\alpha} m_{\beta} = \Sigma I_{\gamma}m_{\gamma}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> m_{\alpha}/ m_{\beta} = \Sigma I_{\gamma'}m_{\gamma'}
> $$
>   where the partitions $\gamma$,$\gamma'$ result from adding to or subtracting, respectively, from $\alpha$ all distinct partitions
>   obtained by permuting in all possible ways the parts
>   of $\beta$. Clearly, all $m$-functions involved 
>   are functions of the same $r$ indeterminates, i.e. have
>   the same number of total parts.
>   The coefficient $I_\nu$, with $\nu = \gamma$ is given by
>   $$
> I_\nu=n_\nu \frac{\dim (m_\alpha)}{\dim (m_\nu)}
> $$
>   where $n_\nu$ is the number of times the same partition
>   $\nu$ appears in the process of adding or subtracting
>   partitions referred to above.

As far as I read, they don't give a special name to these coefficients.

Comment: Not mentioning the details of the reference in the answer, but only (supposedly) on the other end of a link is not a great idea. The link is dead now, and I have no idea where it used to be pointing.

Comment: And is "subtracting" missing after "respectively"? Adding $\alpha$ _from_ something else is bad syntax...

Comment: @Marc thanks for reporting that. I try to fix the link (if possible) and provide more information about the paper in the body of the post...do you have any special interest in the topic?

Comment: @marc sorry you were right. I stripped the reference a bit to fit to the question. Stand by...

Comment: Reading the answer again, I have strong doubts about the division case. What do they mean by that? Note that the monomial function $m_{2,1}=e_2e_1-3e_3$ corresponds to an irreducible polynomial in the polynomial ring $\Bbb C[e_1,e_2,e_3,\ldots]$ and I think this is typical for the $m_\alpha$. But then they cannot be divisible by any other $m_\beta$, and the quotient $m_\alpha/m_\beta$ can only make sense as a formal rational fraction, not a polynomial as the RHS of the equation indicates. So either they are using a curious definition of division, or this is just plain false.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of basic linear algebra to get the answer. Let me
reformulate the question.

1. Let $s_{\cdot}$ be the Schur polynomials and $c_{i,j}^k$ be
   the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients. Namely, with Einstein
   summation convention, $$s_{i}s_{j} = c_{i,j}^{k} s_{k}$$
2. Let $m_{\cdot}$ be the symmetric monomials and $d_{a,b}^c$ be
   such that $$m_{a}m_{b} = d_{a,b}^{c} m_{c}.$$

We want an expression of the $d$'s in terms of the $c$'s.

---

**Deduction**

It is wellknown that both $s$ and $m$ forms a basis for the ring
of symmetric function over $\mathbb{Q}$. So there are matrices
$P, Q$ inverse to each other such that $m_a = P_a^i s_i$ and $s_i
= Q_i^a m_a$ for any $a$ and $i$.

Then $m_a m_b$ equals $(P_a^i s_i)(P_b^j s_j)$, so
$$P_a^i P_b^j c_{i,j}^k = d_{a,b}^c P_c^k.$$

Since $Q$ is the inverse of $P$, we have the formula

$$d_{a,b}^c = P_a^i P_b^j Q_k^c c_{i,j}^k.$$