# Is there a explicit formula for the number of Semi-standard Young Tableaux over $\{1,\dots,n\}$ for a given partition $\lambda$ and a given type $\mu$

Tags: combinatorics, young-tableaux, algebraic-combinatorics

I was given an exercise to give all SSYT over $\{1,\dots,12\}$ of shape $\lambda=(4,4,3,1)$ and type $\mu=(4,2,2,2,2,0,\dots,0)$. Now I was wondering if there is an formula to say something about the number of SSYT in general.

Comment: I assume you mean $\mu = (4, 2, 2, 2, 2)$ (with an extra 2). Based on the correctness of [this code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22867) it looks like the answer is 7. So you don't have too much work to do by hand.

Comment: Oh you are right, I added the $2$. $7$ matches with the SSYT I found. Thanks for the code and the answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [Kostka numbers](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kostka_number).

According to Wikipedia:

> In general, there are no nice formulas known for the Kostka numbers. However, some special cases are known. For example, if $\mu = (1, 1, 1, ..., 1)$ is the partition whose parts are all $1$ then a semistandard Young tableau of weight $\mu$ is a standard Young tableau; the number of standard Young tableaux of a given shape $\lambda$ is given by the [hook-length formula](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula).

Wikipedia doesn't provide a reference. But according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17891/437127) it seems like Stanley says something to this effect in EC2. I recommend following that link and also the link in the comments there to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/18597).

I also found a [relevant paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10801-006-0008-5) that shows that computing Kostka numbers is #P-complete.